# App (iOS) keeps starting default PhoneGap splashscreen, what's wrong?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

Big issue here as I can't find any solution. Basically, I want to start the iOS simulator app (Xcode) with a specific splashscreen for iPhone 6 Plus (1242x2208px). I called that image "splashscreen_iphone6plus.png"

I placed all pics in the folder AppName/Platforms/ios/AppName/ressources/splash and I've been starting app 2000 times changing all kind of parameters. Strangely, it keeps loading the image "Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" that is a 640x1136px (which is not a native size for iPhone 6+ anyway).

In order to understand what was wrong, I tried to alter this image by adding text in it and I simply saved it. That image now loads with my modifications in it!

However, I thrown away Default-568h@2x~iphone.png (trash) and inserted that name into the image I really wanted to load (splashscreen_iphone6plus.png) but that doesn't work! I'm not getting any error or anything I'm just getting the image, modified, that is now located in the trash!!!!

How can that be? I of course made new projects, clean project, deleted app in simulator, etc. but I can't fix this!

Any help would be appreciated as I'm getting desperate here!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Check your config.xml file it shall have the following configs and the image size shall be exactly as specified below:

```
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png"    gap:platform="ios"     width="320" height="480" />
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="960" />
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-landscape-2x.png"    gap:platform="ios"     width="960" height="640" />
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-landscape.png" gap:platform="ios"     width="480" height="320" />
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png"      gap:platform="ios"     width="768" height="1024" />
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png"      gap:platform="ios"     width="1536" height="2048" />
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="2048" height="1536" />
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png"      gap:platform="ios"     width="1024" height="768" />
```